# MongoDB - How to update an object in an array?

Tags: mongodb

My data structure looks like this:

```
{
  "_id" : .....,
  "topicId" : topicId1,
  "category": .....,
  "other things"....,
  "posts": [
    {postId:id1,
     username:.....,
     postBody: 'some text here' 
    },
     {postId:id2,
     username:.....,
     postBody: ' some other text here' 
    }
  ] 
}
```

My goal is to find a document where `topicId` equal to some Id, after that in the document find in `posts`  an object where its `postId` equal to some Id, and finally update `postBody` in that object.

At the end it should look like this:

```
{
  "_id" : .....,
  "topicId" : topicId1,
  "category": .....,
  "other things"....,
  "posts": [
    {postId:id1,
     username:.....,
     postBody: 'some text here' 
    },
     {postId:id2,
     username:.....,
     postBody: 'HERE IS UPDATED TEXT' 
    }
  ] 
}
```

This is how i'm deleting a post:

```
  db.collection('topics').findOneAndUpdate({ 'topicId': topicId }, { $pull: { 'posts': { 'postId': postId } } })
```

But i have no idea how to update it based on my data structure. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

**01)** Example of Document:

```
{
  "topicId" : "5db85e379a17899b8ba631ca",
  "category": "category",
  "other things": "Other Things",
  "posts": [
    {
       postId: "5dae22702486f7d89ba7633c",
       username: "TheUserName",
       postBody: 'Some Text Here' 
    },
    {
       postId: "5db85e439a17899b8ba631cd",
       username: 'TheOtherUserName',
       postBody: 'Some Other Text Here' 
    }
  ] 
}
```

**02)** Query:

```
db.collection('topics').update(
    {"topicId" : "5db85e379a17899b8ba631ca"},
    { $set: { "posts.$[outer].postBody" : "HERE IS UPDATED TEXT" } },
    { multi: true, arrayFilters: [{"outer.postId" : "5db85e439a17899b8ba631cd"}]}
);
```

Answer (score 1):

considering your data is

```
{
  "topicId" : "topicId1",
  "posts": [
    {"postId":"id1",
     "postBody": "some text here" 
    },
     {"postId":"id2",
     "postBody": "some other text here" 
    }
  ] 
}
```

you can use simple updateOne by filter and then $set

```
db.blah.updateOne({ topicId: 'topicId1', 'posts.postId': 'id2'  }, { $set: { 'posts.$.postBody': 'HERE IS UPDATED TEXT' }  })
```

Comment: Your answer did not work and gave error `SyntaxError: missing } after property list @(shell):1:41`

Comment: a , was deleted by mistake after inline editing :), added to answer